# When i run my angular 12 project i get NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)

Tags: compiler-errors, angular12

`NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)[t -> t -> t -> InjectionToken Application Initializer -> [object Object] -> t -> t -> oz -> sz -> t -> nce -> nce -> nce]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for nce!`

i have importet HttpClientModule in my apps.module

Comment: main.js:1 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)[t -> t -> t -> InjectionToken Application Initializer -> [object Object] -> t -> t -> oz -> sz -> t -> ice -> ice -> ice]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ice!
    at eb.get (main.js:1:3105116)
    at kP.get (main.js:1:3106379)
    at kP.get (main.js:1:3106379)
    at kP.get (main.js:1:3106379)
    at ql (main.js:1:3077389)
    at kn (main.js:1:3077466)
    at t.ɵfac [as factory] (main.js:1:3239455)
    at kP.hydrate (main.js:1:3107886)
    at kP.get (main.js:1:3106331)
    at ql (main.js:1:3077389)